# Unable To Invoke Function In A Template Literal

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, template-literals

Hello StackOverflow Heroes,

I have an amateurish question on why I can't call this function in a template literal. The code is return undefined without any errors in the console. I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong, am I missing a return statement?

```
function startCountdown(seconds) {
  let counter = seconds;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(counter);
    counter--;

    if (counter < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

document.body.innerHTML = `<p>Quick! Click to stop the page from self destructing. You have ${startCountdown(
  5
)} seconds.</p>`;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're inserting the return value of the function but it doesn't return anything. And even if you make it `return counter;` this won't extend into the future; the visible value will remain at 5. Fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/grqok53m/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```js
function startCountdown(seconds) {
    let counter = seconds;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(counter); 
        document.querySelector('#countdown').innerHTML = counter;
        counter--;

        if (counter < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

document.body.innerHTML = `<p>Quick! Click to stop the page from self destructing. You have <span id="countdown">5</span> seconds.</p>`;

startCountdown(5);
```

It has a span set with an `id`. You can update this element then with JS.

Comment: This still starts with `undefined`. And the `<span>` should probably be returned by the `startCountDown` function.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a callback that in return provides the seconds:

```js
function startCountdown(sec, cb) {
  const itv = setInterval(() => {
    cb(sec); // Call your Callback, pass sec as argument.
    sec--;
    if (sec < 0) clearInterval(itv);
  }, 1000);
}

// Use your function:
startCountdown(5, (sec) => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `<p>Quick! Click to stop the page from self destructing. You have ${sec} seconds.</p>`;
});
```

That way you can reuse your `startCountdown()` without hardcoding into it unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't return anything from a function implicitly `undefined` is returned. Hence you'll be getting `You have undefined seconds.</p>`

you must return a value from your function.

Even if you return a value from your function, you will get the same value you passed as a parameter because `setInterval` is an asynchronous in nature which means by the time interval starts and ends your function would have already returned the value.

```
function startCountdown(seconds) {
  let counter = seconds;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(counter);
    counter--;

    if (counter < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);

return counter;
}
```

you will get `You have 5 seconds.</p>` if you passed `5` as parameter to your function.